# Container does not start if I map existing in container dir

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a container with directory mapped to host directory.

```
docker run -d --name web1 -p 8080:80 -v /vagrant/web/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d nginx
```

But for some reason if I am specifying directory existing in the container  - container is created (i get ID back) but it does not start.

if I run `docker ps` I do not see the container but if i run `docker ps -a` I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
6b8bde856fdc        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   10 minutes ago      Exited (1) 10 minutes ago                       web1
```

If i do the same but instead of existing `/etc/nginx/conf.d` dir I specify something else - it works.

There is no related records in log `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`

Additional info

- Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
- Ubuntu Trusty

Comment: you should check logs with command: `docker logs 6b8bde856fdc` to show what is the reason?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls /vagrant/web/config` performed on your host please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the content of /vagrant/web/config in the host ?
The problem may be an error in one of your nginx configuration files that prevents nginx from starting. And if nginx doesn't start, the container stops from running.

Answer (score 2):

Run another container with the same settings and `bash` as entrypoint. Afterwards manually start the command from the original container and look for the error:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash --name web2 -p 8080:80 -v /vagrant/web/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d nginx
root@7553b294969f:/# nginx -g 'daemon-off'   

# this is just an example with a badly formatted default.conf file
2016/07/04 08:14:15 [emerg] 10#10: unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line
```